# PWA service worker fetch not working properly

Tags: javascript, python, flask, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm currently working on a PWA using the Flask webframe.
Everything seems to work well until the fetch eventlistener.
I wrote my fetch interception code like this and I don't think it's wrong.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) =>{
console.log("[From Service Worker]", event)
event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(cacheRes=>{
        return cacheRes || fetch(event.request)
    })
  )}
)
```

But when I check the console, only one fetch event is showing in it. In the network tag, it also shows that it's fetching the files from network, not from the service worker.
I checked stackoverflow questions and noticed that it might be the scoping problem, but I the output shows its scope is http://127.0.0.1:5000/, the root directory.
What's more, if I refresh the page with the DevTools off, when I check the console after refreshing, all the fetches are showing there like what it should be. But when I tried to refresh it with the tool on, the fetches were gone again.
Why is this happening?

Comment: If you visit the Service Workers tab in Chrome's DevTools, do you see your page listed as a Client of the active service worker? https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/progressive-web-apps/#service-workers

Comment: Thanks for the link! I found the solution from it.

Answer (score 2):

Your service worker might not refresh when you refresh the browser tab. Close the tab and call the URL in a new tab. Or select "Update on refresh" in Chrome's DevTools > Application > Service Workers.